# CodeIgniter - removing index.php

Tags: codeigniter

Im having some trouble removing the index.php thing on my CI install, the current .htaccess im using is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My CI install is back from the public_html directory and i have changed the config to

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

So my CI looks like the following

```
/core-1.7.3
/public_html/index.php
```

When i type the url i get the 404, but when i put index.php in front of it, it works fine :S

Im confused

Answer (score 1):

Hi
I ve installed that 1.7.3 and this .htaccess worked with this URL-

```
/CodeIgniter_1.7.3/public_html/welcome
```

.htaccess->

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try to change this:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = “REQUEST_URI”
```

Comment: Now its just giving 404 for every page.

Comment: Can u check these things-

1. If your installation is not in the server root you will need to amend the RewriteBase line from “RewriteBase /” to “RewriteBase /folder/”   

2. Make sure your apache uses the mod_rewrite module    

3. Make sure apache is configured to accept needed .htaccess     directives   

[reference- http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/]

Answer (score 0):

Work through Avisek Chakraborty's comment and make sure you've done them all, but
it sounds to me like you don't have mod_rewrite installed correctly.
Make sure it is by using the following test:
http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-test-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-t40.html

It is written for windows but you should get the idea.

If it doesn't work then install mod_rewrite and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need the FollowSymLinks directive for .htaccess rewrites ...

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   </IfModule>
```

The Options directive is in [The Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options)