# Codeigniter doesn't work without index.php

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, httpd.conf, codeigniter-url

I'm using MAMP with alias named works. 
Codeigniter is at `localhost/works/project/web`

controllers doesn't work without index.php before them (`localhost/works/project/web/index.php/auth/register`)

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/works/project/web/'; //with http://

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

(I tried all of them for uri_protocol)

I created and edit .htaccess file at /User/me/works/project/web/
I tired all the .htaccess files about this issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Users/me/works/project/web

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
#Submitted by Michael Radlmaier (mradlmaier)
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404’s
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

creates error, which is:
`[error] [client ::1] File does not exist: /Users/me/works/project/web/auth`

it is same when I use RewriteBase /

mod_rewrite is active in phpInfo.

I couldn't find the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues/14807463#14807463

Comment: Below link solve my issue :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues/14807463#14807463

Comment: Below link solved this issue :)- You can also refer it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues/14807463#14807463

Answer (score 3):

Your `RewriteBase` is wrong. It should not be the relative file path for your server, it should be the relative URL path for your rewrite rules and such. [More info here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

If you've ever used HTML's `<base>` tag, it's pretty much the same principle. If your main localhost URL is `http://localhost`, and your project is in the subfolder `http://localhost/my-project`, then you would use `RewriteBase /my-project/`.

If you didn't use RewriteBase, and your project is in a subfolder, you'd have to add the subfolder to every one of your URLs and rewrites, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-project/index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

Food for thought:

- Start your .htaccess files as **simple** as possible. The more you throw at it right away, the more that can go wrong, and the harder it is to debug. Especially if you're a noob to .htaccess files. Don't blindly copy and paste -- figure out what things actually do.
- The system folder access part is redundant now -- the system folder has its own .htaccess to restrict requests, just like the application folder.

Answer (score 1):

1.Make below changes in application/config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Your Ci folder_name';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

2.use this in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and enable rewrite mode using below command

```
 a2enmod rewrite
```

and Edit the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
change the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All.
```

and finally Restart your server

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't have mod_rewrite on or you did not install it with MAMP

Open your httpd config file and change

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None
```

To

```
AllowOverride All
```

---

uncomment this line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

---

Also make some changes to users here: /etc/apache2/users/username.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

DocumentRoot "/Users/username/where/ever/you/like"

<Directory "/Users/username/where/ever/you/like">
    Options Indexes MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Get more info here http://adam.merrifield.ca/2010/08/09/apache-mod_rewrite-php-and-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/

---

Restart MAMP

---

To find out if mod_rewrite is on, follow this answer in Stackoverflow:

[How to check if mod_rewrite is enabled in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php)

---

Just to be sure your .htaccess is not the issue, could you try this one. It's been tested:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /Users/me/works/project/web/

    # If the start of the URL doesn't match one of these...
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|assets|cache|themes|uploads|css|images|js)

    # Route through index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Access to certain folders are granted above and the rewritebase has a trailing slash.

---

Make sure you have any other nested .htaccess overriding this very one.

Comment: Where are you putting the .htaccess file? which of these directories (/Users/me/works/project/web/) is your default localhost directory (I'm guess web) and which is presently holding your .htaccess? I guess web also. Your .htacess should also be in the same directory as your index.php file. Can you give me a little more details on your directory structure.

Comment: "web" directory has these:
application
system
userguide
index.php
.htacces (the one I am working with)

in application directory there is one more .htaccess which includes:
`Deny from all`

I tried to change it too but didn't work.

Comment: No don't change that one. Is web also your default MAMP folder or is a sub directory. If project is the default MAMP folder could you change rewritebase /web/. If web is, rewritebase / and then restart apache.

Comment: Please see my edited reply. Ensure you have mod_rewrite on. It probably wasn't installed or is turned on in your current MAMP installation. Mod_rewrite is apache, you might have to make the changes I have pointed out above. That should fix things for you.

Comment: I fixed the problem by instead of using .htacces, I write them to httpd.conf. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but are you going to mark it as answered. That would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by instead of using .htacces, I write them to httpd.conf. 
I checked the AllowOverride is All but I'm not sure why .htaccess isn't working. Because of I lost too much time with this issue, I'm going to use this way.
Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use **AllowOverride All** on your vhost:

```
<Directory "/path/to/your/site">
    ....
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your httpd config file
LoadModule **rewrite_module** modules/mod_rewrite.so then **AllowOverride All**

```
          <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs"> //example for xampp
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
               AllowOverride All
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
           </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed codeigniter in a url like the format: http://11.12.34.45/~project/

I tried different suggestions and finally this following url provided the solution:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two files of Apache,
httpd.conf
httpd-vhosts.conf

change this in httpd.conf

```
<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
</Files>
```

to,

```
<Files ".ht*">
Require all granted
</Files>
```

and add below code in httpd-vhosts.conf,

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```