# Avoid controller function in URL codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller messages. And there is a function called index.

```
 class messages extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct() {
           parent::__construct();


       public function Index($userkey=NULL){

                     Some functctions

 }
```

}

Currently my URL is messages/index/userkey. And i want to convert this to messages/userkey.
How can i convert this by routes. please help me

Comment: see this.... http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/234634/#1051485

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the CI Route docunment here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/routing.html

-find 'application/config/routes.php' file

-add your rule to $route array

```
$route['messages/(:any)'] = "messages/index/$1";
```