# Removing index.php from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried to remove index.php from url. I tried more links from linkden but have not worked. I tried following.

1.add .htaccess file with following data,

```
 RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

2.changed in config.php `$config['index_page'] = ''`;

3.activate `mod_rewrite`.

But still not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Arun. I tried that link to, but not working

Comment: Are you trying in LOCAL or in SERVER ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make .htaccess file in root of project directory with following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

modify application/config/config.php with following:

```
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /yourfolder/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The requested URL /ci/controller/functionname was not found on this server. still facing error

Answer (score 0):

Finally the Following code works in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```