# codeigniter how do i setup routing for controller class and method?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI and need some beginner's help from experts.

Here is what my current setup is:
/controllers/

- home.php
- report.php

/views/

- home/index.php
- home/recent.php
- report/index.php
- report/generate.php

the URI i am trying to produce as an outcome:

http://localhost 
http://localhost/report (would load the index.php)
http://localhost/report/generate (would call the method for generate in the report controller)

http://localhost/recent/10 (would call the method for generate in the home controller passing the variable '10')

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['/'] = 'home/index';
$route['recent/(:num)'] = 'home/recent/$1';
$route['report/(:any)'] = 'report/$1';
```

How do i avoid always modifying the routes file for each new method created in a class? so that it would follow:
$route[$controller/$method/$variable] (very use to how .net mvc routing is setup).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need further modifications. In fact, even this line is redundant:

```
$route['report/(:any)'] = 'report/$1';
```

This one is also redundant:

```
$route['/'] = 'home/index';
```

since the default controller is set to 'home' and the default method is **always** `index`.

Look at how CI works with URLs: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

So, `/localhost/report/generate` would look for the `Report` controller, and load its `generate` method. That's how it works out-of-the-box, no routing needed.

And this route is fine:

```
$route['recent/(:num)'] = 'home/recent/$1';
```

If will take the URL `/localhost/recent/123` and will load the `Home`, controller, `recent` method and will pass `123` as the first method parameter.

Comment: Thanks shomz, but I am getting a 404 error: The requested URL /recent/10 was not found on this server.

[edit] seems like this works fine: http://localhost/index.php/recent/10... how do i ignore or exclude the index.php in the URL?

Comment: You're welcome. It's described in the URL I gave you in my answer, and there are many answers here, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. The htaccess update made the difference.