# Unable to access CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, file-get-contents

I had two `CI` projects in my local machine named `client` & `server`. The `client` has a controller `Welcome` which has two functions `__controller()` & `greet()` with echo statements "hello from controller" and "hello from greet" respectively. The `server` has a controller named `cron` which has a function `test()` with the following piece of code:

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 10
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://localhost:2016/Welcome/greet/";
echo $url . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(file_get_contents($url, TRUE, $context));
```

When I accessed the `test` controller through browser, it displayed `Hello from controller. Hello from greet.` as I had expected.

Later I moved both `server` & `client` projects to two different `LAMP` servers and accessed the same `test` controller through my browser but the result was only `Hello from controller.` Am I missing something here?

Comment: please provide more information

Comment: @riya Sorry I'm not sure what you are looking far but I've posted everything I did.

Comment: create routes for ur controller action plz refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288239/codeigniter-how-do-i-setup-routing-for-controller-class-and-method or https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html