# Not Able to remove "Index.php" from URL in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am new in codeigniter and i am trying to remove index.php from URL in Codeigniter but not able to do this.
I wrote code in my .htaccess file-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My Apache **mod_rewrite** is enable.

But still got 404 error when i am trying to access any controller without using index.php.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: have you enabled mod rewrite module. you have remove index.php in config.php file

Comment: yes . i have already mention this in my question and i have already removed index.php form config file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url duplicate

Comment: i did every thing which are suggested in above Ref . but still facing same problem.

Comment: Sometimes, and that is depending on server (GoDaddy for example), you need to append question mark after `index.php`. I.e. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`. Also google for *far in space codeigniter htaccess* and try to use code provided.

Comment: i checked every thing and could not find where i m making mistake. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Is the code I'm using, it works on every hosting platform I've used it on.

Comment: Also application/config/config.php - change 
**$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';** to **$config['index_page'] = '';**

Comment: @BushraShahid wat error are you getting implementing this answer

Answer (score 1):

This should help you,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code of htaccess file.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|css|js|robots\.txt)    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

you can find your answer refference here

[My .htaccess file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249932/my-htaccess-file-in-000webhost-is-not-working)

moreover can you share your base url with us? as this error may be due to wrong baseurl set.

Comment: @Bushra kindly note ? sign after index.php