# My .htaccess file is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

i have added my project on free hosting 000webhost and my all files are listed in public_html/ directory.
project is built in codeigniter.
i have added htaccess file at public_html/.htaccess which contains

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

but this does not working for me is there any issue in htaccess?

Comment: like this one RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?req=$1 [L,PT] ?

Comment: Your .htaccess file is fine. What error message do you get? Do you have access to the web servers' error log?

Comment: no my js,css files are not being loaded plus links not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this (it works for me in both, locally and remotely):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|css|js|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You need to create a folder called "public" in the root rolder and sub-folders for css, js etc.

Comment: CodeIgniter, by default, has an `index.html` file in every folder. First directive should point on that one in most cases. `DirectoryIndex index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry from all my htaccess is ok but i had an extra chracter in my base url which was causing problem.
Sorry again.