# CodeIgniter not routing on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, web-hosting

this is the first application that I upload to an online server. I created the application on CodeIgniter 3.0.1 and uploaded it to the 000webhost.com . But the problem is, none of my links are being routed. I have checked online and my `.htacess` file seems to be correct. I have checked this question [My .htaccess file is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249932/my-htaccess-file-in-000webhost-is-not-working)  and I have the same problem as He does, but the correct answer didnt work.

Heres my `.htacess` file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|css|js|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: whatz your error ? what you want to achieve ?

Comment: You need to create a folder called "public" in the root rolder and sub-folders for css, js etc.

Comment: Could you provide error what you get? Is it 500 Error or something else?

Comment: @safin  I defined a route: 
$route['club'] = 'controller/method' .. But when I try to acess this route using websitename.com/club , it gives me a 404.

Comment: what is the url when showing 404

Comment: My website is http://sigede.comli.com/ Im getting a 404 when I try to acess http://sigede.comli.com/club

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes
please add to question route files, probably the issue in route

Comment: can You give directory structure in location where .htaccess lyes?

Comment: what if you call sigede.comli.com/controller/method ?

Comment: Please add your route configuration it seems misconfiguration in routes.php cause i can access codeigniter default controller method http://sigede.comli.com/index.php/welcome/index and you need to add index.php before your route or controller/method

Comment: could you please provide me the output of phpinfo:

<?php

phpinfo();

Comment: set the htaccess root path bro

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes did you tried my answer ?

Comment: Here it is @motto http://sigede.comli.com/#modalidades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Can you make sure you have created that particular "controller" & it's "method" to which you are trying to route? I mean can you literally verify their spellings?
2. Can you also try to create a rule:

`$route['club'] = 'welcome/index';`

Can you see if the above rule works or not? Do you have any other controller by the name of 'club.php'?

Comment: Yes. Everything works fine on my local server. It just doesn't work on the webhost

Comment: 1. Do you have your $config['base_url'] set? If it's blank, can you set that to your base url & see?
2. Does creating any other route work at all? For example:
`$route['abc'] = 'welcome/index';`
Does something like this work?

Comment: 1. Yes, it is set as following: $config['base_url'] = 'http://sigede.comli.com/'; 2. No, creating other route doesnt work at all.

Comment: Does it help if you temporarily remove the  htaccess file & then see if it loads those routes?

Comment: I did remove the htaccess and it doesn't load.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I assume on your localhost you don't have a subdomain setup?
Can you change your last line in .htaccess file to this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` ?

Comment: I think we're getting somewhere now. I've changed that last line. Now the 'abc' route works, but the others don't work.

Comment: I see. Can you show what your route file looks like with the 'abc' route as well as the 'club' route which doesn't work? I do see that 'abc' does indeed show the proper page.

Comment: I renamed my controllers. Capitalized the first letter. Now it works correctly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Good to know. So you renamed the controller files from let's say: 'sigede.php' to 'Sigede.php' ? I still see 404s on your site though based on the routes file you provided earlier.
Thank you for the bounty & marking the answer. :)

Comment: Yes, i renamed it from 'sigede.php' to 'Sigede.php' and 'class sigede extends CI_Controller' to 'class Sigede extends CI_Controller'. Yes, those 404's are because I'm changing some stuff there. You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with you.

check .htaccess is hidden or not, if hidden try show hidden file, and voila

Answer (score -1):

Try this and tell us if it works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

p.s. I hope Your file is ".htaccess" (not .htacess)

if it's still not working, try to edit `index.php` file by adding this on the top of it:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
die;
```

this must show You that htaccess properly rewriting to index.php file.
if still not getting proper work, contact to hosting support.

btw this snippet taken from here and has many thanks: https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

Comment: I tried that .htaccess and it didn't work. The echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; returns -> \

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes in all cases? have You tried to open in browser: http://yoursite.com/something ?

Answer (score -1):

Since you have mentioned as 404 error. Can you make sure all the project folders have proper permission to execute ?

Set permission as 0755 to the project folder and all its sub folder.

Then give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

To ensure that the wrong part is `.htaccess` file, you need to access your website with `index.php` on the path.

For example, you need to visit http://example.com/index.php/book instead of http://example.com/book.

If the first URL can be accessed, then it is likely your `.htaccess` is not correct.

I typically ship this `.htaccess` in my CodeIgniter project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

And last, please ensure that your `rewrite` mod is activated in your Apache server (contact your hosting provider if you use shared hosting).

To activate it, run this command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then, restart the service:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I needed to register 000webhost and check the subdomain structure for solving that problem. As I suspected, it's creates a folder for subdomain. Therefore your .htaccess file is not working correctly. You need to point subfolder as rewritebase:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /sigede/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|css|js|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```