# routes in codeigniter from a subdirectory

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, routes, subdirectory

Im having trouble trying to make routes work on the production system(nginx). It works on localhost which is running apache.

File structure

```
/var/www/example.com
   --application
   --system
adm
   --application
   --system
   --controller
       --user
       --example
   --model
        --users_model
    --views
        --admin/
              --login
              --signup_form
        --example
```

I keep getting 404 error when trying to access the controller from adm folder.
My routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'user';
$route['404_override'] = '';

/*admin*/
$route['admin'] = 'user/index';
$route['admin/signup'] = 'user/signup';
$route['admin/create_member'] = 'user/create_member';
$route['admin/login'] = 'user/index';
$route['admin/logout'] = 'user/logout';
$route['admin/login/validate_credentials'] = 'user/validate_credentials';
```

user controller view is displayed just the static content and everything else gives 404.

/var/www/example.com/adm/application/config/config.php

```
base_url = http://example.com/adm
uri_protocol = AUTO
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, TIA.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /adm/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
`                                                                                                              htaccess file from **adm** dir

Comment: Do you have [these](http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter) settings?

Comment: Yup. Its not working, still showing 404 not found. I'm actually unable to access the controller from the URL as well, like [example.com/adm/user/index] after removing all the route variables except for the default route.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add index.php after your project folder like:

`www.site.com/project/index.php/user/signup`

If you want to access your site without index.php then see this post [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19197074/1578380)

Comment: It doesn't work. My htaccess is configured to remove index.php

Comment: I got it to work on xampp on the production server but still no luck with nginx.