# URLs not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I'm new to codeigniter. I have installed codeigniter on Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm able to see the welcome page. However other controllers that I create are not working.

I get a message the page not found. I have looked around a lot but could not find anything to fix my issue.

Can anyone kindly help?

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->model('login_model');
}

public function index($msg = NULL) {
    $data['msg'] = $msg;
    if ($this->session->userdata('validated') == false) {
        $this->load->view('templates/header_login');
        $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
    else {
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
```

The default codeigniter page works completely fine. But If I change the default controller with mine then I get a message that page not found

Comment: show your controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: @RejoanulAlam it has lots of answers & none of it is marked as the correct answer. Which one should I consider?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you install Codeigniter,

You can always access any controller,  with http://sitename/index.php/controller/method/parameter. You remove index.php from url with .htaccess file.

You can access your login page with http://sitename.com/index.php/login

Sample .htaccess code:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`

Comment: I'm new to .htaccess. Can you please help me with that.

Comment: Read this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-remove-index-php-file-from-codeigniter-url/

Answer (score 0):

To access your custom controller all you have to do is use `index.php` in your URL. Such as if your controller name is `User` the use this url `http://localhost/your_project/index.php/user`

and if you want to go any other method in `User` controller like `create` then use

`http://localhost/your_project/index.php/user/create`

But if you don't like to see `index.php` in your URL then you may place a file in your root directory name `.htaccess` and put followings in this file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Ref: [More Details](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)

now your URL looks like `http://localhost/your_project/user/create`

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter works like this

www.yourdomain.com/controller/function

if you add index function in your controller you can visit directly

www.yourdomain.com/controller/

check that you added index function

Please add .htaccess in your project root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /stock
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```