# CodeIgniter: Removing index.php from the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I was trying to remove the `index.php` from the URL, on my WAMP server [**THIS**](http://tutsnare.com/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter/) worked perfectly, but for some reason on my actual hosted server it's not.

I just created on my current Linux Ubuntu Server a sub-domain, 
under `/var/www/tools.example.com/public_html`

I checked if `mod_rewrite` is enabled using a .php file I uploaded to the dir with this:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
```

and mod_rewrite is under "Loaded Modules". 
so no worries here.

the .conf file I created in etc/apache2/sites-available/tools.example.com.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName tools.example.com
    ServerAdmin walid@example.com

    ErrorLog /var/www/tools.example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/tools.example.com/logs/access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/tools.example.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/tools.example.com.conf/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            # changed from None to FileInfo
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

where `AllowOverride All` so using mod_rewrite with .htaccess is enabled.

I don't know why this is still not working. Any idea why?

the content of the .htaccess file in the main dir:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Edit #1:

I already went through all first 9 solutions in this post: [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Would help to provide your .htaccess.

Comment: re-read `I was trying to remove the index.php from the URL, on my WAMP server this worked perfectly,` 

"this" has a link in it.

Comment: I updated my post with the .htaccess file content to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **path** is incorrect in your .conf file for the directory directive. Your document root listed should be the same as your Directory directive. So I don't think it's picking up the `AllowOverride All` directive.

Change this

```
<Directory /var/www/tools.example.com.conf/public_html/>
```

To this

```
<Directory /var/www/tools.example.com/public_html/>
```