# Remove index.php?/name and redirect to /name

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to redirect the below url

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php?/Welcome/
```

to

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/Welcome/
```

and I have tried the below in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

The above code taken me to below

```
http://localhost/CodeIgniter/?/Welcome/
```

I need to remove that ? mark for avoiding duplicate urls in seo. Can anybody help me

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: @Suchit I already tried it and not works for this case

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And you have to enable mod_rewrite
If you are using PHP version lower than 5.2.6 -> Remove the ? from index.php

Comment: Won't this redirect all pages to `index.php`?

Comment: This is not the case am asking. I need to redirect the urls and remove the ? from URL for SEO

Answer (score 0):

You can try your code this way.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I have tried this and not working..:(.. Its even not redirect anything.. I changed R=301 and no luck

Comment: Does your .htaccess work? is it enabled? Also did you add `RewriteEngine On` above the rules?