# How to remove index.php from url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following code is in my .httaccess file.

```
#write your project folder name as rewritebase
RewriteBase /Codeignitor3D/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It's give the 500 internal server error

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 2):

Try this Rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

In your `config.php` file,

```
//Find   
$config['index_page'] = "index.php" 
//and replace it with
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps to remove index.php from url codeigniter:

Config changes: Go to “application/config/config.php”

Find below code:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Replace with the below code:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

.htaccess changes: If you not have any htaccess create new and place it on your root.

Note: if you have codeigniter in subdirectory change RewriteBase / to RewriteBase /subdir/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now open your site pages you will found clean url with no index.php. so your all url looks like http://example.com/controller/method. Now any of HTTP request for index.php will be treated as a request for your index.php file.

If still issue: Need to apply one more config changes.
Go to “application/config/config.php”
Find below code

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Replace with the below code

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Now you have fully done to remove index.php from url codeigniter and getting clean url in codeigniter.

Comment: @ParasDalsaniya eventually, change this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure mod_rewrite is installed and enabled
- Make sure apache's site config file allows the use of .htaccess
- Check apache's error log as well as PHP's error log, since you are getting 500

Review http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html