# Removing index.php in Codeigniter gives 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

This is my online hosting directory structure

```
-- /
   -- up
   -- .logs
   -- public_html
      -- application
      -- system
      -- user_guide
      -- .htaccess
   -- DO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE
```

In my config.php, I wrote this code :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

in my .htaccess file, I have this following code :

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to remove index.php from my URL, so it will show `mydomain.com/class/controller` instead of `mydomain.com/index.php/class/controller`

It runs smoothly in my localhost, I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 with LAMPP server. However, when I tried above all code online, it shows me the 404 error page.

This is my soon-to-be-if-working-properly website : onesource.esy.es

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your mod_rewrite rules are redirecting to /index.php instead of /codeigniter/index.php.

Put this in your .htaccess file:

RewriteBase /codeigniter/

Comment: Where does `codeigniter` come from? Because I don't have any folders with such name. All of my codeigniter directories stored in a folder named `public_html`

Answer (score 0):

In my instances (using CI 3), I have changed the uri_protocol in the config.  Try going to **application/config/config.php** and changing to:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Hope this helps.  If not, maybe there are more suggestions here:

[CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in **.htaccess** file

**.htaccess** file must be in the root directory of your CodeIgniter Project Folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In ***application/config/config.php*** file

**`$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;`**

By default it is false, change it to TRUE

**`$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`**

And try again to access your controller in the browser without index.php

I hope this will work for you. (According to CodeIgniter version 3)