# Error while removing index.php in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, frameworks

When I'm trying to remove index.php form Codeigniter url with below code in `.htaccess` file, my project folder hide.

`.htaccess` code (from codeigniter user guide):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My `localhost` When I'm not using above code(everything in OK) :
[image]

My `localhost` when I add that code to my `.htaccess` file (I can't access to my project folder) :
[image]

Comment: where is your htaccess file relative to that folder? it should be inside the folder

Comment: Have a look at this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: @Dale Yes it's inside that folder.

Comment: What type of server is your CI app hosted on?

Comment: Because you need to use RewriteBase / for more details https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

I forgot to enable `rewrite-module` from my Apache Modules in wampp server and that was the problem !

Thanks all.