# Object not found! message when trying to reach views inside the sub-folders in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, routes, url-routing

I am new to code igniter and have the following setup in my project files

Models:

Model1

Model2

Controller:

Controller1 [which has only index method]

Controller2 [which has index method of its own]

View:

Views/MyFolder1/index.php [which is view for Controller1]

Views/MyFolder2/index.php [which is view for Controller2]

Routes.php has following code

```
$route['MyFolder1'] = 'Controller1/index'; // Route to Controller 1 index 
$route['MyFolder2'] = 'Controller2/index'; // Route to Controller 2 index
$route['default_controller'] = 'Controller1';
```

config.php has

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname';
```

When I try to call http://localhost/projectname/Controller2/index.php or
http://localhost/Controller2 I keep getting Error 404 Page not found . Can you please help resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Put index.php before controller name

Comment: Like http://localhost/projectName/index.php/Controller2

Comment: @FaranAli - It worked, but why we have to pass view name before the controller ? according to CI documentation the url structure should be example.com/class/function/id/  ?

Comment: You need to configure .htaccess

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add index.php before controller name, Like localhost/projectName/index.php/Controller2

to fix that follow this answer

[CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

You should call it as http://localhost/projectname/MyFolder2

The key of the `$routes` you used is the url you should open.

Comment: Hello,  Thanks for your reply. I have tried entering http://localhost/projectname/MyFolder2 and http://localhost/MyFolder2 which always gives me 404 page. However if I use http://localhost/projectname/MyFolder1 or http://localhost/projectname/ it fallback to the Controller1 and displays the page. Not really sure whats going on here with calling Controller2.

Comment: Try to look if there is a duplicate of `MyFolder2` route... routes that has `(:any)` at first segment of url could be the problem too.

Comment: Nope, I am pretty sure that there are no duplicate names involved and have included what my Routes.php and other project files look like  in the question.