# CodeIgniter not run in route

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

When I download project in https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/downloads.html

**CodeIgniter v2.2.0**

When I run http://localhost/qldv, I get result as welcome page of codeigniter, but when I register in routes.php with route

```
$route['admin/welcome'] = 'welcome';
```

When I go to web with link: http://localhost/qldv/admin/welcome

I don't get welcome page. Result is

> Object not found!

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't disable having to put index.php in the URL (using an htaccess file), this route won't work. This would: `http://localhost/qldv/index.php/admin/welcome`

To disable index.php in the url look at this question:
[CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in your Welcome Controller.

```
public function admin()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Put this code in your Welcome Controller.`public function admin()
>   {
>       $this->load->view('welcome_message');
>   }`