# Want to generate redirct rule for htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am having trouble to generate redirection rule I tried so many possible ways but those are not working.
Here are the details:

**1)** Current link: https://app.abcd.com (Showing in url)

**2)** Redirect to: https://app.abcd.com/index.php/login

**3)** Should be renamed as : https://app.abcd.com/login

I have **tried :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://https://app.abcd.com/index.php/login/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Didn't work!

Any help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url  please check this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php/login [L,R]
```

This will redirect your homepage **/** to **/index.php/login**

You can also accomplish this using RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ /index.php/login/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine on



RewriteBase /example/  



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php/$1 [R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)/([^?]*) index.php?_cmd_=$1/$2  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_cmd_=$1  [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTACCESS**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Open **config.php** and do following **replaces**

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess for codeigniter:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

And in config.php:

change:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

to:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
IndexIgnore *
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your .htacces file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```