# Object not found! - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I enter this url on my browser :

```
localhost:8085/farabi/Fateme/index
```

I don't know why I get this error :

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404

Fateme.php :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Fateme extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_fateme');
    }
}
```

---

config.php :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8085/farabi/';

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

my `htaccess` in root folder (/farabi):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: solved: I should use this url : `http://localhost:8085/farabi/index.php/Fateme/index`

Answer (score 0):

Remove your htaccess and replace it with the below one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also read this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/19197074/4481606