# Getting error in codeigniter : a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: php, codeigniter

Earlier my menus were working fine and suddenly it started giving error

> Not Found The requested URL /allbound/index.php was not found on this server. 
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: http://dograpublicschool.com/confluent/travelling/index.php/flightsd //add index.php before function name

Comment: how to resolve this issue? i donot want to show index.oho in url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the access url.

In this case access the url like this http://dograpublicschool.com/?ndex.php/confluent/travelling/flightsd. It is working with me.

**Remove index.php in codeigniter**

You can remove the index.php by editing your `.htaccess` as shown below

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope that helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

//add index.php before function name

dograpublicschool.com/confluent/travelling/index.php/flights‌​d

to remove index.php from url

try

[CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).