# Unable to remove index.php from Codeigniter 3.0 URL

Tags: apache, wamp, codeigniter-3

I am unable to remove index.php from CodeIgnitor 3.0 URL. I have applied so many solutions but nothing worked. I am using WAMP 2.5 . rewrite_module is active in Apache . $config['index_page'] = ''. My htaccess file which is in the root folder is as follows

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /Reporting/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|img|css|captcha|robots\.txt) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Reporting is the folder in www where all the files are there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems with removing index.php with the **default** .htaccess code, but I managed and this is how my .htaccess looks like now.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 


<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>  
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you friends. I have done it. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You have this in Codeigniter documentation - [READ](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)

Comment: Did you tried this method - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28828919/6042030