# Removing index.php using codeigniter 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to remove the 'index.php' link from the url project folder but it return error 404 Page Not Found.
My default URL is: 
http://localhost/training/belajaradmin/
and it working just fine. As well for this URL

http://localhost/training/belajaradmin/index.php/login
But, when I put this URL as I remove the index.php:
http://localhost/training/belajaradmin/login 
 The code does not work.

Im using codeigniter 2.2.6. The code below is the name of the file and the changes that I have made.

> .htaccess at root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !&(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> config.php in 'application' folder

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/training/belajaradmin/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

> autoload.php in 'application' folder

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

> routes.php in 'application' folder

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login";
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: I did that but it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .htaccess add following line after `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteBase    /training/belajaradmin/
```

Edit config as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Thank you! it does working now like a charm. I just edit .htaccess file and then it work like I want. As for the config.php I did not make the changes as you suggest as my css look different.

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Activate the mod_rewrite module

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: For windows please follow the steps given here -  https://webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting