# Controller and Routes Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in MVC and would like to ask about controller and routing in Codeigniter.

I do my project in my localhost.

When we call localhost/projectname, it goes to the controller Welcome which has index function to view main.

this controller, I also have another function to change to another page,
like this :

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('main');
    }

    public function changeLanguage(){

        $this->load->view('main_in');

    }
}
```

How can I move to do a href in the view.
In my main.php (view). I have :

```
<a href="changeLanguage">Link</a>
```

But it's not working.
Then I change the link to :

```
<a href="index.php/Welcome/changeLanguage">Link</a>
```

and it's working.
But on the second view (main_in.php). I want to make a link to go back to the first place. I call it but got error 404 again.
Any clues ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: set base_url() your localhost/folder path. than write as  <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Welcome/changeLanguage">Link</a>

Comment: thanks I got the idea to use the base url for my link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should change `config.php` in config folder

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

And your link should look like this

```
<a href="<?= base_url() . 'welcome/changelanguage/'">
```

Comment: thanks I got the idea by using base url , I use your solution but the link still needs index , such as :
<?= base_url().'index.php/welcome/changeLanguage

Comment: If you need ```index.php``` and you want to remove it, then you have to use .htaccess file. This answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: change .htaccess to:
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|images|robots\.txt|public)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css³js³jpg³gif³png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]