# .htaccess file does not working on godaddy server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Can someone tell me why this code would work on my local server but not on godaddy server?

I get the following error on godaddy...

I have creating one codeigniter project and host on godaddy server but .htaccess file does not working

my problem is "https://www.tripbrip.com/index.php/home/app_view" this same url come in my url side but i want to remove index.php in this link

my directory structure is this:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php/?$1 [NC,L]

my config file:
$config['base_url'] = "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

This file run in my localhost but not working on server.

I have use many code but still problem remain same .

If I browse to http://example.com/bootstrap.php I get a 404 resource not available at /

Comment: Try looking at solutions posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0):

The following setting works fine for me.

```
RewriteEngine on -MultiViews
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

in `application => config => config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; // should be blank
```

instead of

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Comment: i really thanks for your answer. i used this code as per your suggestion but problem still remain same. so any other way to solve this problem please suggest me

Comment: @ShivrajHipparge I have updated my answer again. Hope it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try put this on your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteBase    /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

And for your config file. maybe u can just empty it.

`$config['base_url'] = '';`

If still error, you can try this

```
$config['base_url']  =  "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```