# anchor codeigniter duplicate

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

this

```
echo anchor('perkalian','Perkalian');
```

is supposed to take me to:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/hitung/perkalian
```

but instead, it takes me to:

```
http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/perkalian
```

what is wrong with my code?

routing : `$route['default_controller'] = 'hitung';`

Comment: Have you declared `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';` in config/config.php?

Comment: as d.coder said. also specify your base_url in .htaccess file

Comment: yes..i declared base_url @d.coder

Comment: how do i specify base_url in .htaccess file?
my .htaccess file contains
{<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>}

Comment: Your anchor has `perkalian` and you said it should take you to `hitung`. So is there any routing applied? If yes then please add that into your question too.

Comment: how do i specify base_url in .htaccess file?
my htacess file contains `<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>`
@AbdullahMallik

Comment: i edited the question...i meant it should take me to `perkalian` @d.coder

Comment: echo anchor(site_url('perkalian')); try like this

Comment: And yes it is surely issue with / give that and check output

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a forward slash before URL in anchor like this:

```
echo anchor('/hitung/perkalian', 'Perkalian');
```

Or you can use `site_url()` method also:

```
echo anchor(site_url('/hitung/perkalian'), 'Perkalian');
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Then may be you can try removing index.php from URL which you can find on CI documentations. [More on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: What is the output of `echo site_url ();`?

Comment: localhost/CodeIgniter/index.php/hitung/perkalian