# remove index.php not working on aws EC2 server

Tags: codeigniter, amazon-ec2

I am trying to remove index.php of my codeigitor application which is hosted on EC2 instance of ubuntu OS. But unable to get the solution.

Below is my htaccess file added to the root of my application

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|font|woff|ttf|svg|eot|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: This needs to be fixed in the config.php settings- see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0):

1. Add .htaccess file in you CI root folder and add this code

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   #RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. Remove idex.php from CI

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = ''; 
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   ```
3. Then

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```

   and change:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/>
   AllowOverride All
   ```
4. Restart the apache