# Using segments and and URI for Get variables using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, uri, codeigniter-3

Okay,

So I am looking to do something similar to index.php/show?p=1, however I know that using GET is disabled in Codeigniter by default. So I was wondering how I would set this up in a controller using URI and Segments, so it would look like index.php/show/1. Or is this not possible?

Obviously the '1' will be changed based on a value in the database.

I hope this makes sense, if not, please let me know.

Comment: best if you get rid of index.php so that it becomes yoururl/show/1

Comment: Change the href to `show/p/1` and get it using $this->uri->segment('2').

Comment: This documentation has all the answers and great examples. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

You need to enable mod_rewrite module on your server and set-up .htaccess file with awoid index.php, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: `$this->uri->segment(2)` [Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html).

Answer (score 1):

1. `$_GET` is not disabled by default.
2. Doing the URI segments thing is as easy as adding a single route, and this is covered by the [tutorial in the official documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html).

Answer (score 0):

To have the URL `http://example.com/index.php/show/1` do as you ask you would modify the file **application/config/routes.php** to accomplish the task.

Assuming `show` is a controller and you want the index() method of the controller to handle the above URL you need to do a couple things.

Define the index method to accept an argument

```
public function index($arg) 
{
    ...
```

Add the following to **application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['show/(:any)'] = 'show/index/$1';
```

If you want to use some method other than `index()` to handle the chore - let's say `doShow()` then the route looks like this.

```
$route['show/(:any)'] = 'show/doShow/$1';
```

And the method is

```
public function doShow($arg) 
{ 
   ...
```

No matter what method used - `index()` or `doShow()` - if you don't pass an argument in the second URI segment you will get a 404 - Page Not Found screen.