# how to remove further url link from codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have creating a website using codeigniter framework which having following link like (xyz.in/index.php/abc) but I want to open my index page using only xyz.in. how can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: also change $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; to $config['index_page'] = ''; in config file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: Set `$route['default_controller'] = 'abc';` in `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'`.

Comment: https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root_folder_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

more info -> [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: yes, look at this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make .htaccess file put this code in it and place the file outside your Application folder.