# Routes in Codeigniter not working on different server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Let me inform you this first. This application is working pretty fine on live server currently, however we needed to move it to a different server with a different domain.

Issue is: It gives 404 error on every other page except for index. Loading through index.php works fine.

**For an example:**

www.test.com/main/login //This gives 404 error

www.test.com/main/index.php/login //This loads fine

Because everything is working fine currently, I made changes only in `$config['base_url']` and in database config file. There have been no other changes in any of the files.

Also, this solution provided by somebody in a different questions is already tried out and this doesn't work. Solution is to create .htaccess file with below code & setting `$config['index_page']=''` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Current server is VPS & provider is GoDaddy. New server is Shared hosting and provider is GoDaddy. I'm not getting the root cause of this happening, can somebody point out to the possible solution?

**EDIT**

I'm attaching a screenshot for an error, it's not typical 404 error page. In case this helps.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Godaddy, you need to alter this 2 things.

In your .htaccess file, replace

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

With the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Then is your **application/config/config.php** :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Both this changes should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: This doesn't work. Now it says, it doesn't able to locate /index.php. I attached a screenshot in my answer, please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, this or the other thing worked. I was not putting my subfolder name in Rewritebase.