# Codeigniter route URL contact page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new in Codeigniter I'm not sure how to use Codeigniter Routing. I've created the `Contact.php` in the controller folder and `contact.php` in the views folder.

In routes.php I have put `$route['Contact'] = 'controller/contact';` but when I enter the url http://mytest.dev/contact/ it shows **404 Page Not Found. The page you requested was not found.**

I want when I enter "http://mytest.dev/contact" it will show the contact page

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only need routes when you want to change CodeIgniter's standard handling of URLs. See [CodeIgniters URL](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) documentation for details.

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question should include code. In this case sharing your controller would be good. That said, I think @ArmKh has given you the answer.

Comment: This is [https://github.com/abkr/codeigniter-contact-form/blob/master/controllers/contact.php] contact on github @DFriend thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Contact extends CI_Controller {
        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index() {
            $this->load->view('contact')
        }
    }
```

In `CI` there is an `index.php` in the URL ( by default ). So, you can access your page with this url http://mytest.dev/index.php/contact

For removing it from `URL` and have it like you want you need to add `.htaccess` file in your project directory

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19197074/6068342) answer for it

Also, you don't need to change your `routes.php` every time after creating a new page. Leave it like this

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'; // or contact
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `$route['Contact'] = 'controller/contact';`

Tell us your controller's class name and which function/method did you use from the above you are referencing to `contact()` and that controller name doesn't make sense. You route will normally be in lowercase too.

If you named your class `Contact` (which seems like it) then you need to put a `.htaccess` file in the folder where your `index.php` or `base_url` resides (or root directory) and then remove the value in `application/config.php` as `$config['index_page'] = '';` so that you can access it from http://mytest.dev/contact

To make it clearer. The format should be `$route['AAA'] = 'BBB/CCC';`

AAA is the url path of your choice
BBB is the name of your controller's class
CCC is the function/method of the page you want to show

If you didn't add the htaccess, you must put `/index.php/` before your preferred path.