# Getting rid of index.php from mywebsite.com/admin

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website developed in PHP using Codeigniter framework.

I have included `.htaccess` file in it and it works fine for all my web pages and I don't get index.php, but when I type my admin url which is

`mywebsite.com/admin`

it goes to

`www.mywebsite.com/index.php/admin`.

The `index.php` only appears when I try to go to my admin page.

I tried a lot to get rid of it, I even included a copy of .htaccess file both in the admin controller and view folders as well but nothing works. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: in the config.php I have done $config['index_page'] = ''; already but it does not work in the admin case.

Comment: show your view link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: You will get the complete answer on the above link

Comment: In my case I tried doing what is there in the link but it does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Make sure it should be on root folder and set your `base_url` in the config.php.
e.g
`$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/home'`

Answer (score 0):

add following changes,

**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```