# Codeigniter base_url() adds index.php to my path

Tags: php, codeigniter, base-url

I have this code and I want to add a stylesheet file to my page in my CI project. I have set the config file to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/project/';
```

However, the link that tries to get this file includes index.php and in return I cannot link the stylesheet. What is wrong with my code?

```
<link href="../<?php base_url();?>vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I echo the base url it shows localhost/project/.

This is the error: GET http://localhost/project/index.php/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: I tried all these solutions. None of it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$config['base_url']` needs a full URL complete with protocol. Try this.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

If you're using ssl then the protocol should be `https://`

Answer (score 0):

As a very advanced solution to your **Question**

1- You have to set your **.htaccess** file to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

2- set your **config.php** file in **config** folder to:

```
$url = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$url .= "://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$url .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['base_url'] = $url;
```

and

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

With this trick, you even don't need to set **$config['base_url']** manually :)