# CodeIgniter - Cannot access to Controller file

Tags: codeigniter

I tried to use the .htaccess file to make the index.php disappear from the URL.
Here is my current .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I used the site_url() function to load my page like this :

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/welcome/corporate') ;?>"><div>Home - Corporate</div></a>
```

And I am having this issue :

> The requested URL /mysite/welcome/corporate was not found on this
>   server.

In the Welcome.php file, I have a function called corporate :

```
public function corporate() {
    $this->load->view('index-corporate.php');
}
```

I changed the config file already like this :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I feel like my problem is basic but can't find a way to solve it !

Thanks for your help

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, my problem was coming from my controller name : I forgot the capital letter at the begining (welcome instead of Welcome)