# htaccess codeigniter remove index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, apache2.4

I have hosted codeigniter application in apache2.4 with php7.2 docker environment. Not able to resolve routes correctly.

PATH

> /var/www/html/apps/sample1

browser PATH

> http://localhost:8080/apps/sample1/

working fine but routes controller and actions is not get resolved until i use index.php

> http://localhost:8080/apps/sample1/index.php/admin/logn

**Correct Expectation**

> http://localhost:8080/apps/sample1/admin/logn

.htaccess current configuration, Apache mod_rewrite already enabled

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /app/innovative_travel_web/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>  
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value short_open_tag 1
  php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
  php_value post_max_size 20M
  php_value max_execution_time 200
  php_value max_input_time 200
</IfModule>
```

Kindly please guide me, how can i fix it.

Comment: have you check your apache rewrite mode is on?

Comment: Yes Apache mod_rewrite is already enabled

Comment: Reading their [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html) is usually an excellent start. Can you please explain why their rewrite directives did not work for you?

Comment: this might be helpful to you, check it @SyedRaza
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url?rq=1

Comment: in config file remove index.php in index_page variable.

Answer (score 0):

1) create htaccess like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

2) in application/config/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then your .htaccess You `RewriteBase` might look like below based on your root folder or just `/` if the app runs in root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /folder_name/

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set in config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in .hta

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /apps/sample1/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

U need to specify the directory too since your path is **/var/www/html/apps/sample1** not
**/var/www/html/**