# Remove index.php from url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have the same problem as many people to remove the index.php from url in codeigniter.

i always done all response from precedent answer, but i always can access to a url with index.php

this url work : https://www.domaine.tld/Test
but i can access : https://www.domaine.tld/index.php/Test (work too)

i dont have any link in my site which include index.php but my question is about how redirect url with index.php to dont have duplicate content.

thanks for your answer.

Comment: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/ maybe htaccess will solve the problem for you. Just redirect "/" to "/index.php"

Comment: who knows of the existence of https://www.domaine.tld/index.php/Test except you? you write: "I don't have any link in my site which include index.php", the part "remove index.php from url" is answered extensively here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter have beautiful documentation.you can find all things related Codeigniter is in Codeigniter user_guide
for now to solve your issue create `.htaccess` file in root and paste following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And then also remove the `index.php` from

```
application/config/config.php

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

changes to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Learn more at: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `config.php` under `application/config/config.php`, you need to change two configs there, setting your `base_url` and deleting the `index_page` value:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your_base_url';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then in you `FCPATH` create a `.htaccess` file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now everything should work just fine (unless you are using `lamp` cause in this case your need to do some extra steps in your `apache` configurations).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response. i always do that, but not worked and i dont understand why....
i'm on apache2 / rewrite module enable

i modify the virtual host too

        AllowOverride All

```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.phtml index.php
    php_admin_flag engine On
     AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful on lamp

---

> **Put this code on your `.htaccess file`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

> **open**

```
application/config/config.php
```

remove index.php

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

then set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'your site base_url';
```