# Why is the auth/login path returning 404 error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I am new to Codeigniter and I have recently started a project using Codeigniter v3.10 and the Ion-Auth library for user actions.

When I try to access the login page `base_url/auth/login` I get a `404 error`.How can I troublehsoot/solve this? I don't see anything in my network tab in the browser.

I copied and configured the files as presented in user docs.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look in your Apache logs, this should point you to the right place to check.

Normally in:
/var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: Is your codeigniter `index.php` file directly in `htdocs` or is it in `htdocs/somefolder`, further is your `base_url` set? did you follow this for htaccess: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base_url/index.php/auth/login
or use .htaccess to remove index.php