# how can i remove index.php? while redirecting from other site?

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I am having 2 domain 
EXAMPLE:- example.com and result.com both built on codeigniter.
 I want to redirect all urls of example.com to result.com so i redirected all the urls from cpanel of example.com to result.com.

so, when i put a url of exapmle.com/folder/xyz after when it redirect to result.com it shows :-  https://result.com/index.php?folder/xyz

Is there anyway to remove the index.php?   ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: .htaccess code vary depending on hosting server. In some hosting server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use an extra ? in the last line of above code. The following line will be replaced with last line in applicable case: