# How to remove index.php from subdomain nested folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have main domain http://example.com on my root directory and all of my subdomains are in catalogs folder /catalogs/subdomain1,/catalogs/subdomain2.Currently my subdomain url in http://subdomain.example.com/index.php

I want to remove index.php from my subdomain.

My Root .htaccess file code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect on https:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My Subdomain .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect on https:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
Options -Indexes

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: can you show us your root application folder?

Comment: @curiosity [Link]https://ibb.co/QmV51g0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code and update RewriteBase ***/root_directory/subdomain_folder_name/***  at your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root_directory/subdomain_folder_name/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: in Main htaccess or subdomain htaccess?

Comment: at your project root .htaccess or your can update in your own .htaccess  RewriteBase with directory path details.

Comment: You just add subdomain_folder_name at the third line of code and try.

Comment: Follow this following steps also.use this URL to follow all steps to remove index.php.  https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-htaccess-remove-index-php/

Comment: Update  RewriteRule Like this        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mop/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: i have given the folder names so please define code according to given folder name

Comment: You have to make two .htaccess files and put them at directory root of subdomain1 & subdomain2 and use above code with   RewriteBase /subdomain1 /    at file 1 and     RewriteBase /subdomain2 /  on 2nd file.

Comment: I have update above code please check and try.hope this time works for you.

Comment: have you you follow all steps which i suggest you like update base url in config and all.

Comment: Yes, I have followed all the steps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://subdomain.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ folder [L]

DirectoryIndex index.php
```