# how to hide index.php and controller name in codeigniter by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

i want to hide index.php and controller name from my codeignier url website
also i want to replace this term ?seo=test-product ad /test-product

i have mention my htaccess file below please guild me how to fix this issue i have tried many things none helps

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: also i dont want to affect my form actions

Comment: already given in the CI document.

Comment: Firstly check if the mod_rewrite.c is enabled on your server or not. and then follow this article https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**first we adding (.htaccess)(it is only extention file) file extention in our project directory**

*it is my project file directory location*
http://localhost/demoproject 
*demoproject is my project name*

**copy below code and create (.htaccess) file and paste it under (.htaccess) file

these file create under project directory**

```html
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


# Disable Directory Browsing
Options All -Indexes
```

**one more (.htaccess) file create into view folder**

**copy below code and  paste it under newly created (.htaccess) file**

```html
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

*normally code controller file*
**DemoController.php**

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class DemoController extends CI_Controller 
{
 public function index()
 {
        $data['demo'] = 'hello world';
        $this->load->view('DemoView', $data);
 }
}
```

```
enter code here
```

*normally code our view file*
**DemoView.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
      <h1>
       <!-- $demo is the $data of object that defind our DemoController. -->
           <?php echo $demo ?>
      </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**run localhost and only type localhost/project_name/controller_name**

**here we use** *demoproject* **as project name and** *DemoController* **as controller name**
**http://localhost/demoproject/DemoController**

*if your code not execute then please comment*

Answer (score 0):

try this

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
> ```