# Access codeigniter website homepage only at example.com and example.com/index.html and not at example.com/index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to access codeigniter website homepage only at example.com and example.com/index.html and not at example.com/index.php, I tried redirecting index.php to index.html with htacess but homepage becomes inaccessible. I do not want to show it is a php website.
though I am able to display homepage at example.com/index.html by adding below in application/config/routes.php

```
$route['index.html'] = 'home/index';
```

But example.com/index.php is still accessible which I want to redirect to 404

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to hide index.php and controller name in codeigniter by htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57800579/how-to-hide-index-php-and-controller-name-in-codeigniter-by-htaccess)

Comment: Why would you want to hide the fact you are using PHP? if for security, it's futile in terms of security through obscurity

Comment: set `$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';`, note: this doesn't resolve index.php to index.html but all other pages can be shown as "a_page.html". And you could hide(remove) index.php completely. See https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=302,L]
```

This redirects any *direct* requests for `/index.php` to `/`.

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we only redirect direct requests and not rewritten requests by the Codeigniter front-controller (that appears later in the `.htaccess` file). Otherwise, you'll get a rewrite-loop (500 Internal Server Error response).

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is not set on the initial request from the client (ie. evaluates to an empty string, `^$`). However, when the request to rewritten by the Codeigniter front-controller to `index.php`, `REDIRECT_STATUS` is set to the string `200` (representing a 200 OK HTTP status), so the above condition fails to match and the request is not redirected when Codeigniter rewrites the request to `index.php`.

You could redirect to `index.html` as well using the above method, but `index.html` must be set up as a route in Codeigniter as you suggest.

> But `example.com/index.php` is still accessible which I want to redirect to 404

If instead you want to serve a 404 (although a redirect, as above, would be preferable) then simply change the `RewriteRule` to read (keeping the *condition* as before):

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [R=404]
```

Comment: not my DV, but I think, if you send index.php to 404, the whole Codeigniter framework wouldn't work. Codeigniter's Index.php is setting up the system settings of the framework

Comment: @Vickel That's what the check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is for - as stated in my answer. This ensures that _only_ direct requests from the client are served with a 404 (or redirected). Rewritten requests (to `index.php`) by the Codeigniter front-controller are not  touched - `index.php` is still accessible to PHP/Codeigniter.

Comment: ah, ok, thanks for pointing that out, didn't know/try. I usually hide index.php with .htaccess and add url_suffix in my config (as per my comment at the OP)

Comment: @Vickel I've updated my answer with a bit more explanation about the use of the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable.

Comment: @Vickel "I usually hide index.php with .htaccess" - Same method as above. Although you can also match against `THE_REQUEST` instead - same result, except that the regex required to match against `THE_REQUEST` is often more "complex".

Comment: Thanks! redirecting this way to 404 works well, earlier the way I was redirecting made complete website inaccessible. Don't know why this question was closed and the two references given to close the question do not match at all with this question. Any way I got the answer. Thanks again