# Remove index.php from codeigniter with language like index.php/en

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to remove the index.php from my site https://yesomega.org/. For that i have followed these step

[CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: .htaccess code vary depending on hosting server. In some hosting server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use an extra ? in the last line of above code. The following line will be replaced with last line in applicable case:

// Replace last .htaccess line with this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

After followed this i could not solve and index.php/en. When i move to another page, it is showing me error 404.

https://yesomega.org/index.php/en/pricing

So is there any problem in this ? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`. Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

In the application/config/config.php file

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectName';
 $config['index_page'] = '';
```

Try using only this three lines. Hope it will work fine.

Comment: No, it is not working. It is coming with "/en". please let me know what to do ?