# Codeigniter URI Parameter Mapping

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I have a site that I want to pass directly to the controller method without going through the class in codeigniter.

https://website.com/product_number instead of https://website.com/index/product_number

I want that to go directly to my main controller method.

config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

controllers/Welcome.php

```
function index($product_number)
{
  //process $product_number output
}
```

Would this be possible in codiegniter?

Comment: you need to change your `.htaccess` file to remove `index.php` from `url` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open config/routes.php then add this line to it

`$route['(.+)'] = 'welcome/index/$1';` I hope this helps your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Open

/application/config/config.php

then find this line

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://website.com/index/';
```

and Replace with

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://website.com/';
```

I hope this Aswer very helpful for you.