# How to Remove index.php in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I try to remove the index page in Codeigniter

the first step I do this
//old Code

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php”
```

//New updated code(Only Need to remove index.php )

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

then for second step i do this 
creat file .htaccess in root of codigniter then put this code source

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

> but it's the same problem and I can't refresh the web page

**with index page the URL work: http://localhost:8089/codeigniter3/index.php/Hello/dispdata** 
**but without index page don't work http://localhost:8089/codeigniter3/Hello/dispdata**

Hello is the controller,
finally thank for help, :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

Comment: I try all this answer but any success :(

Comment: Check it `$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";`

Comment: @Dmitry Why set this to `"REQUEST_URI"`? The OP appears to be using `PATH_INFO`?

Comment: Any success with your routing?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, you installed it in `/codeigniter3/`

This should fix it:

```php
// remove index.php
$config['index_page'] = ""

// Allow installation in a subfolder of your webroot
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

And keep your rewrite settings, they are ok.

Comment: "The problem is, you installed it in `/codeigniter/`" - the "root of codeigniter" would seem to be `/codeigniter3/`. But why would this be "the problem"? If you change the `uri_protocol` setting to `REQUEST_URI` then won't it (incorrectly) include `/codeigniter3` as part of the routing?

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter url routing should come to your rescue. Refer: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new File In Main Folder Named as (.htaccess) and paste this code in .htaccess file.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /Enter your folder name/
   ```
2. Removes access to the system folder by users.
   Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
   previously this would not have been possible.
   system can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
   ```

When your application folder isn't in the system folder
This snippet prevents user access to the application folder

3. Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.

   ```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
   ```

Checks to

```
 Rewrite Cond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$    
 Rewrite Cond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
 Rewrite Cond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]    
</IfModule>
```

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite

And then do this

```php
//remove index.php
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code in your `.htaccess` file on root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below process:

1. Create `.htaccess` file in the project root folder
2. Check whether [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is enable on server?

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`
   ```

This will resolve your issue.
Let me know if you are still facing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this step:

1. remove index.php from `$config['index_page'] = "index.php"`
2. create `.htaccess` in the project root folder like below code

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /codeigniter3/
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|fonts|images|js)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
   ```

   Then try `http://localhost:8089/codeigniter3/Hello/dispdata`

I hope it will fix your problem!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
> ```

Since you are passing the correct URL-path as *additional pathname information* (path_info) in your `.htaccess` directive then try explicitly setting this in the config:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'path_info';
```

Unless this is set explicitly then it will try various methods, which may be failing since you have now removed `index.php` from the URL.