# Redirection issues on live server | Codeignitor

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, redirect

I am using Codeigniter as a PHP framework on the live Ubuntu 16.04 server. I have installed apache2 and PHPMyAdmin on the machine. Created a virtual host. Right now the site is opening when I enter the following URL: seasonjourney.com/index.php/destionation/goa on the web browser but when I click on the goa link on the home page it redirects to seasonjourney.com/destiontion/goa. How shall I correct it? I am from a sysadmin background so doesn't know much regarding PHP code.

.htaccess File:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

[image: 404 not found]

[image]

Comment: Could you please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: Do you have the mod_rewrite active on your apache?