# Codeigniter, Routes. Keep the URLS

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I have a too old website to recreate.
Do not have sources, but all the links looks like

http://example.com/about.html

http://example.com/contact.html

http://example.com/countryname.html

http://example.com/countryname/cityname.html

Well the owner says: "This is Joomla", 
but I wonder why the links are so simple,
just like if it was numbers of separate '.html' files.

I don`t use Joomla at all and I prefer the Codeigniter.
But is there any way to keep the URLS the same?

**For example, in my view**

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('/welcome/countrieslist/germany');?>" class="menu__link">Germany</a>`

which gives 
http://example.com/welcome/countrieslist/germany

I would need to have
http://example.com/germany.html

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add an identifier to the url, like:

```
http://example.com/germany-c.html
```

Based on that `c` identifier you can route any url while knowing what that URL represents. In this case, `c` represents country.

Then add the route in config/routes.php:

```
$route['(:any)-c.html'] = 'welcome/countrieslist/(:any)';
```

Comment: @Vadym K. The way you're proposing it's hardcoded. Not realiable for many URLs or another people. Add .html in your route to use the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Donboo.

After a while I think the most simple way is

`$route['what-I-would-like-to-have-in-url'] = 'mycontroller/mymethod';`

Then I need to redefine base_url function in order to add .html to all the urls.

Strange, but

`$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';`

does not add anything.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add a prefix to all your Url's provided you have already deleted the /index.php from the framework url [CodeIgniter removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url)

```
`$config['url_suffix'] = '.html'; //Config.php`
```

//Routes.php

```
`$route['about'] = 'Controller/function';// example`

`$route['germany'] = 'welcome/countrieslist/germany';`
```

Then append this to your link in the view

```
`<a href="<?php echo base_url('germany');?>" class="menu__link">Germany</a>`
```

Routes can equaly be extended with many parameters. Just take a look at the framework official manual under the topic