# Codeigniter 2.1.4 in seperate folder doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I setup my Codeigniter version 2.1.4 on Hostgator. When I put all the files (including application, system, public etc.) in the `public_html` folder, everything works as expected. But I decided to take all the files and folders out of `public_html` folder and just leave what is inside of public folder inside of `public_html`. So the application, system, .htaccess file and all the other thing are in (webroot/codeigniterfolder/). I was able to access my main site [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com). But when I navigate to another controller, say [www.abc.com/order](http://www.abc.com/order), it breaks and displays a 404 error. I have to manually add [www.abc.com/index.php/order](http://www.abc.com/index.php/order) for it to work.

I tried all day today to make it work but still no luck. I mess with the .htaccess file and route and everything. but still no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: The htaccess file needs to be in the public_html directory alongside the index.php file

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url

Comment: Thank for helping. I thought htaccess file is suppose to be hiddent and has to be in the root folder?