# iPage "No input file specified." on /admin page

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, fastcgi

I'm having this problem my app which is build in codeigniter 2.14 was working fine in my localhost using xammp but when i migrated it to my hosting server which is iPage.com i can no longer access my dashboard it prompts a No input specified error.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /

 # If the user types "index.php" or "admin.php".
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin\.php|images|robots\.txt)

 # If the user types just "admin".
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^admin$ admin\.php [L,QSA]

 # If the user enter in any admin section, like "admin/section".
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^admin\/(.*)$ admin\.php/$1 [L,QSA]

 # If the user types any site section, like "site/section".
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you share your .htaccess code..?

Comment: i attached my htaccess

Comment: i can already access the panel but i need to put .php on my on the url

Comment: [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this using cgi bin on my root folder

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to the `.htaccess` file :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44415149/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.