# CodeIgniter .htaccess index.php rewrite not working on user directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a little problem with codeigniter, I have a .htaccess for rewrite the index.php it works great if I put my projects on /var/www or if I make a virtual host for it.

But I want to use my user directory such as http://localhost/~userdir/myproject. If I use my user directory when I'm trying to do request to a controller like: http://localhost/~userdir/myproject/signup I get this error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server.

This is my current configuration:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['encryption_key'] = 'myencryption_key';
//all remaining is the default config
```

This config works great on http://localhost/ and also on production enviroments with a domain like http://example.com/ but not on my user directory http://localhost/~userdir/project/

What I doing wrong? Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I found a solution in [codeigniter forums](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-1016.html), first I need to add RewriteBase line as follows:

```
RewriteBase /~userdir/myproject/
```

Then, remove the slash before index.php on last line.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Someone said that

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favico​​n\.ico)
```

is redundant, the following two lines of code cover it,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

> and all other real files/directories. They basically say "if the request is not for a REAL file, and the request is not for a REAL directory, pass the request to index.php. Presumably everything from the above line is a real file or directory, so it's not needed at all.

So, my final .htaccess is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~userdir/myproject/   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It works well locally with http://localhost/~userdir/myproject also on production with http://example.com/~userdir/myproject

Comment: and dont forget to change the apache configuration as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14807463/1537413

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the first slash berfore index.php like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That not work for me, I get this: 

The requested URL /home/userdir/public_html/project/index.php was not found on this server.

Comment: sorry, i did't see that you removed the index.php from config. try to put the $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Answer (score 0):

**The Local Solution**

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]`

**The Online Solution**
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`