# uss .htaccess hide index not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is how I do in my `.htaccess` file, it's perfectly work on my local server

- Windows 7
- WampServer with PHP 5.5 Apache 2.4.9

http://api.app/facebook/show will show the correct result

But in my Linux server

- PHP 5.4.39
- Apache 2.2.3
- CentOS 5.11

http://api.app/index.php/facebook/show I have to do this, how to fix it?

Comment: Is rewrite module enable in apache config?

Comment: I just add in hosts file redirect to locahlhost, `127.0.0.1 api.app`

Comment: Yes, it's enable, otherwise `index.php/facebook/show ` won't work, because I don't have  directory named `facebook/show`, it's from Controller

Comment: `index.php/facebook/show` will work even if it is disabled because there is no need of rewrite rules. Try removing `index.php` and see if it works.

Comment: of course it's not work, that's why I am here....

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783666/codeigniter-htaccess-and-url-rewrite-issues

Comment: Ok, check two things 1. rewrite module is enabled or not, 2. AllowOverride All for the directory.

Comment: After I open AllowOverride All in httpd.conf it's work, thak you very much